# What Code level changes are required to meet Google play new policy regarding SMS and Call Log

Tags: android, sms, policy, calllog

Apologies for open question because its at the moment, its not 100% related to coding. 
As we all knows that Google has upgraded his Call Log and SMS policy and asked 
developer to compliance with it.
Below is my app link

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tekxperiastudios.callloganalyser

Can anybody please suggest me what is required by developer side or I just need to submit permission declaration form. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try sms retriever api, click on [SMS Retriever](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

Comment: Please read question again so you may be able to answer my question properly.